# ComboBox selection doesn't update when using records?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, record

I'm trying to get a ComboBox to accept an `ObservableCollection` of records, but for some reason the combobox isn't updating. What am I doing wrong? I tried pairing down to the smallest code that shows the issue.

A simple window with a ViewModel, containing only the offending ComboBox:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="200">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Index}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" />
</Window>
```

The ViewModel contains only 2 properties, the selected index and the collection of items:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace Sandbox {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<DataType> Items { get; } = new();

        private int index;
        public int Index {
            get => index;
            set {
                index = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new(nameof(Index)));
            }
        }

        public ViewModel() {
            Items.Add(new("Item1"));
            Items.Add(new("Item2"));
            Index = 0;
        }
    }

    public record DataType(string Text) : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

The real DataType has more properties, but even with this simple object that's basically a glorified string, trying to change the selection in the UI doesn't work.

If I just use `ObservableCollection<string>` everything updates the way it should. But if I drop a breakpoint at the beginning of `ViewModel.Index.set`, I notice that the property isn't ever getting set.

Any idea how I can change the code to get this to work? Or is it just that records don't work with ObservableCollections?

Comment: It works as expected if your record does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Since records are typically used to define immutable data models, there shouldn't be such an implementation in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

From my experimentation, if I replace the `record` with a `class`, everything just works:

```cs
    public class DataType : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        public string Text { get; }
        public DataType(string text) => Text = text;
    }
```

I have no idea why the combobox works with the class but not with the record. Maybe it has something to do with the extra methods implemented by records.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```cs
public record DataType(string Text);
```

[Class vs Record: Difference between class and record type in C#](https://josipmisko.com/posts/c-sharp-class-vs-record)